# Issues in populating currency symbol except dollar in python

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to apply num_format using openpyxl.

```
ws[cell].number_format = '_("$" *  # ,##0.00_);_("$"* (#,##0.00);_("$"* "-"??_);_(@_)'
```

The above works fine, but when I am trying to use below line:

```
ws[cell].number_format = '_ [$€-x-euro2] * #,##0.00_ ;_ [$€-x-euro2] * -#,##0.00_ ;_ [$€-x-euro2] * "-"??_ ;_ @_ '
```

Then I am getting error as:
`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 04: invalid start byte`

! more strange issue I am facing is, above both condition works fine in my local window machine but I am getting this error if I am running from window server.

I even tried using `u`, `r` and `encode('utf-8')`...

Comment: The fact that you're getting a `SyntaxError` rather than a more specific error suggests to me that this is a source code encoding issue, not a problem with the code's actual contents. How are you copying the code over to the server? Do you have a `# coding: foo` declaration on the first or second line of your source file (as specified in [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/))?

Comment: Can you provide the sample data of column on which you are performing the operation. It seems to be an encoding issue and also you have the luxury in python to use `babel` library for populating currency symbol

Comment: How are you transferring the file to the server? What is the native encoding of Python on that server?